# How to deal with duplicate xpath in webdriver Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an app which is angularJS based. I have some check box which have same relative `xpath` and same `CSSselector` path. Absolute `xpath` is not working at all.
I had tried. How to handle this?

> .//*[@id='subjectId']/div[1]/label

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If in your case `.//*[@id='subjectId']/div[1]/label` returns multiple `elements` then you need to use index to determine single element as below :-

```
(.//*[@id='subjectId']/div[1]/label)[1]
```

**For `cssSelector` you need to use `:nth-child(n)` for indexing..**

**Note** :- If you want more better solution, you need to share your HTML as well.

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: .col-md-5.checkboxClass.padding-right-none.padding-left-none>label   this is css selector of 6 check box

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the x path and added "@for='Asses_21']" in relative x path from HTML as in HTML all duplicate x paths have different "Asses"
 now it looks like this.

```
".//*[@id='subjectId']/div[1]/label[@for='Asses_21']"
```

its working now